# Spring-cloud-gateway Docker-compose

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, spring-cloud-gateway

My goal is to implement Spring-cloud-Gateway as a reverse proxy which I plan to eventually utilize as a reverse proxy in tandem with Keycloak for microservice security. The issue I am currently having is as follows:

- Run a microservice in docker without Spring-cloud-gateway
- Run Spring-cloud-gateway with default settings and a single route to redirect to a microservice that exist inside Docker

This works as intended and redirects to the microservice when using localhost:8080. When I then include the Gateway into my Docker-compose and build the container it says "this site can't be reached" but all other services inside of the container are reachable via their ports. I need help determining why this is happening an I suspect it is because of my docker-compose.yml file.
Here it is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  react-web:
    container_name: react-auth-demo
    build: "./ReactJS-Auth/"
    volumes:
      - "./app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      - demo-network
    depends_on:
      - spring-cloud-gateway

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
    container_name: keycloak-service
    volumes:
      - //c/tmp:/tmp
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
    networks:
      - demo-network
    depends_on:
      - spring-cloud-gateway

  spring-cloud-gateway:
    build: ./gateway-test
    container_name: gateway-test
    ports:
      - 6000:6000
    networks:
      - demo-network

networks:
  demo-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is the code for the gateway:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
    return builder.routes()
            .route("1", r -> r
                    .path("/**")
                    .uri("http://192.168.99.100:3000/"))
            .build();
}
```

The request is as follows: http://192.168.99.100:6000/ this should redirect me to the react-web service.

And lastly here is the link to the source code:
https://gitlab.com/LibreFoodPantry/modules/usermodule-bnm/Demo

This project is for an Independent Study in college. So all help and advice are very much appreciated even if it doesn't relate to the issue at hand. Thanks.

Comment: Hi George ! Could you please provide sample of request ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mykhailo I added an example request.

Comment: Could you please provide docket host machine ip . I think ip is invalid inside spring cloud gateway

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura The docker host machine ip is: 192.168.99.100